# How to create a disk partition that would be visible and usable in windows

Tags: dual-boot, disk-management

I have a dual boot machine and 30 gb of unallocated space. I tried to create a disk partition in windows disk management, but that screwed the grub and I wasn't able to get the boot screen. I was given the grub restore prompt. After too much playing around with live usb, i couldn't get it working and had to re-install ubuntu.

So, i think i can make a partition from ubuntu but I'm unaware of how to do so.

So, can you please let me know, how should I create the partition out of 30 gb unallocated space so that It is visible and usable in windows (let's call it e: drive)?

Any hints.

Comment: The partition will NEVER be visible in Windows, it is very much Microsoft's OS and not compatible with anything else, it cannot mount an EXT4 (Ubuntu) drive, stuff like this is why we don't use Windows :) There are 3rd party applications that can access the drive, but they are not the same as native support, check these ones out http://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make it easy type partition in search box, it will give you partition software. click it, you will find GUI is very easy like windows partitioning.

create partition there and make it FAT32

done.

Comment: windows has NTFS file system. How do it make it so that is usable in windows too?

Comment: The traditional way is to assign a drive letter to the partition to make it accessible. Alas I'm no windows expert and would have to try&error it myself.

Comment: Why not format the partition to NTFS? I have an NTFS data partition, accessible by both systems, which I use repeatedly to exchange data between the OSes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gparted. If gparted is not installed in your system run this command to install gparted.

> sudo apt-get install gparted

Now right click on the **unallocated** space and and click on **New**. Free space preceding should be "0", File system should be "**ntfs**" and if you want to use this new partion as only for storage create as "**Logical Partion**". Then click on **Add** button. Go to **Edit** tab and click on "**Apply All Operations**". And then you are done. You can use this partion on both windows and ubuntu.

If you select fat32 as file system then you will not able use files larger than 4GB but it will be usable in both system.